# how to use the jquery hover this keyword to show the currently selected element only

Tags: jquery

Upon hovering class div.results I want to show span.prod_desc to show

How can I achieve this.

```
<div class="results" style="width: 600px;">

<div class="prod" style="width: 265px;border: 1px solid black;float: left;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 5px;position: relative;">
<span class="prod_que" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 5px;padding-bottom: 10px;">Question</span>
<span class="prod_desc" style="position: absolute;display:none;">Hello World</span>
</div>

<div class="prod" style="width: 265px;border: 1px solid black;float: left;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 5px;position: relative;">
<span class="prod_que" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 5px;padding-bottom: 10px;">Question</span>
<span class="prod_desc" style="position: absolute;display:none;">Hello World</span>
</div>

</div>
```

I tied this but it's showing all upon hovering, I want only the currently hovered element to show.

```
    jQuery("div.results").hover(function()
{
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").show();
    },
    function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").hide();

});
```

Please suggest something. Thanks

Comment: Did you get the answer that you are looking for? If you have issues please update your question/comment, shall try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:- <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nFAve/)</kbd>

<kbd>[Refer Toggle](http://jqueryui.com/toggle/)</kbd>

This uses the `div.results` as the context element.

```
 jQuery("div.prod", "div.results").hover(function () {
     jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

you are binding hover on result div. and  all description spans are children of that div. thats why all are showing up.

try this

```
jQuery("div.results > .prod").hover(
function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").show();
},
function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").hide();

});
```

i hope this will help, it will show the description of currently hovered div.

Comment: i have made edit in answer. now it will bind hover to children of results

Answer (score 0):

Since `.prod_desc` is not direct child of `.results`, so you need to use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to find the all the `.prod` divs first before applying `find`:

```
jQuery("div.results").hover(function()
{
    jQuery(this).children('.prod').find(".prod_desc").show();
    },
    function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.prod').find(".prod_desc").hide();

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vBYFA/)**

Comment: it's showing both at the same time at Fiddle. I want only the selected one to show.

Comment: @RIK Then you need to apply hover on `.prod` instead of `.results`. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vBYFA/1/